# Show AlertMe link not working in search results webpart

Tags: 2013, 2010

I checked on the "**Show AlertMe link**" in the settings in webpart properties of the **search results** webpart, but the status of it getting changed to unchecked when I edit it again. It is not getting saved and not showing the alert me in the bottom of the search results.

[image]

This happens in Sharpeoint 2013 on-premise version

Answer (score 1):

Your Search alerts might be turned off.

**To enable or disable search alerts**

1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is an administrator for the Search service application.
2. In Central Administration, in the **Application Management** section, click **Manage service applications**.
3. On the Manage Service Applications page, click the Search service application for which you want to configure search alerts.
4. On the Search Administration page, in the **System Status** section, locate **Search alerts status**.
5. The search alerts status displays as **Off Enable** or **On Disable**.
6. By default, search alerts are turned **On**. Click **Disable** to turn off search alerts or click **Enable** to turn on search alerts.

NOTE: The **Alert Me** link will appear a few minutes after search alerts are turned on. If search alerts are turned off, this icon does not appear.

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718244.aspx

You can find the status on the System Status page of the SSA

[image: Search Alert Status Enabled]